# Sendkeys dropping letters inconsistently

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using `(new Actions(driver).sendKeys(String).perform()` to send input to webdriver. However, I keep getting inconsistent results. Sometimes String is sent in perfectly, sometimes missing one or the other letter, even when the string itself is just a few characters in length.

I even tried sending the string one character at a time (using a for loop) and I'm still getting the same inconsistent behaviour - it's dropping keys less than before, but still not 100% accurate.

What could be possible reason for this, and how to solve this issue?

I'm using Chromedriver, Java/JUnit and the keyboard layout is set to US.

Comment: I've never seen anything like this... have you tried the same code on a different machine (maybe some process on the computer is some interfering?)

Comment: A couple of times - it seems to work fine, but then it doesn't always fail on my machine either, so I can't be 100% sure if it's just something on my machine or not. Though, if it was, what kind of processes could have this kind of interference?

Comment: That is weird, can you reproduce it with FirefoxDriver? Can you try some different keyboard layout (en)? What version of driver are you using? Also, look into here: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=405

Comment: Also...I don't know why this would make a difference, but have you tried it without using Actions?

Comment: This issue doesn't seem to crop up in Firefox, only chrome, and as I said, only sometimes there. As for without using Actions, I'm assuming you mean using a specific element to sendKeys to? In that case, my reason for using Actions is because I am unable to select the element in question. But the issue has has not cropped up when element.sendKeys is used elsewhere.

Comment: I see something similar in an extjs app.  I thought it might be that the textbox was very briefly disabled and therefore there was a race that made it occasionaly ignore the first key stroke... however I added in a wait for the element to be displayed and enabled and it hasn't helped.  Did you have any luck with this?  I'm considering rewriting my sendkeys method to check the value it tried to write has actually been written!  Seems a little extreme though

Answer (score 0):

I'm still unclear exactly what was causing this - I see inconsistent failure to send all keys to some extjs components.  I'm not sure if this is extjs doing something wierd or selenium being a bit flaky.  We weren't doing anything odd in making the string or in calling send keys (except the additional wait to check the element is enabled and displayed) though so it doesn't feel like its something in our code.

My solution was to repeatedly send the keys until they visibly stick.  I've wrapped the selenium api for a number of reasons so all calls to WebElements are routed through a class called WrappedElement which has the send keys method:

```
    public void SendKeys(string text)
    {
        Func<string> errorMessage = () => string.Format("couldn't send keys {0} entered either {1} or {2}", text, Text, Value);

        Action actionToTry = () =>
                                 {
                                     _element.Clear();
                                     RawSendKeys(text);
                                 };

        Wait.RepeatedlyTry(actionToTry, () => Text == text || Value == text, errorMessage);
    }

    public void RawSendKeys(string text)
    {
        _element.SendKeys(text);
    }
```

A simplified version of the wait method looks like this:

```
    public void RepeatedlyTry(Action actionToTry, Func<bool> completed, Func<string> errorMessage)
    {
        Wait.Until(d =>
                  {
                      actionToTry();
                      return completed();
                  });
    }
```

Where Until just calls Until on a configured `DefaultWait`